# Hikari "Add connection elided"

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow, hikaricp

I am getting the following messages running a task in spring cloud data flow.

```
DEBUG 13167 --- [spring_batch146] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-2 - Add connection elided, waiting 1, queue 2
```

I can't find any information on it.

Comment: Do you find solution?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The log message indicates that your application experienced a sudden burst of traffic and database connection requests triggered asynchronously were "merged".

You can find additional information relating to this feature in the [Welcome to the Jungle document](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/blob/dev/documents/Welcome-To-The-Jungle.md).

Comment: "In point of fact, as soon as the pool hit zero available connections, right around 800μs into the run, HikariCP began requesting connections to be added to the pool asynchronously. If the metrics had continued to be collected past the end of the spike -- out beyond 150ms -- you would observe that an additional connection is indeed added to the pool. But only one, because HikariCP employs elision logic; at that point HikariCP would also realize that there is actually no more pending demand, and the remaining connection acquisitions would be elided."

Comment: I have not got your answer. I am facing the same issue. Will you elaborate your answer a more please?

Comment: There is no indication here that there is a sudden burst of traffic and Hikari does not merge connection requests, it just has a sophisticated strategy for how to fill/drain the pool.
But the link to the docs helped.

Answer (score 0):

After looking into the source code, my conclusion is this:

"*Add connection elided*" means that Hikari is currently not trying to create more connection, because it is already trying to create two ("*queue 2*") and there is one client waiting for a connection ("*waiting 1*").

If Hikari gets exceptions while creating new connections, then they are logged - if there are no logged exceptions, then the connection creation is hanging.
If Hikari can not create new connections, then it raises exceptions like this

```
java.sql.SQLTransientConnectionException: HikariPool-1 - Connection is not available, request timed out after 30002ms
```

on the clients that try to obtain a connection.

The behaviour has changed in Hikari 5.1.0 (at least I could not find the log messages any more).

Answer (score -1):

I have the same case, opening many at once in parallel threads.
And in the cloud environment, timeout failures are occurring.

Anyone with any help?

"Add connection elided, waiting 17, queue 18"

Comment: This section is for solution not for asking the question. You can add that in the comment section