# HikariCP lots of connection timeout causes java.lang.OutOfMemoryError

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, sql-server-2012, hikaricp

I am having an issue in production in my springboot application which uses HikariPool

**Springboot**: 2.7.4

**Java**: 1.8.0_281

**Tomcat**: 9.0.71

**Database**: Microsoft SQL Server 2012

**application.properties**

```
crm.pool-name=crmPool
crm.maximum-pool-size=600
crm.connection-timeout=30000
crm.max-lifetime=180000
crm.idle-timeout=180000
crm.leak-detection-threshold=180000
```

Because I have multiple datasources I am creating the connection pool as follows :

```
public class HikariCPDataSource {

    private static HikariConfig crmConfig = new HikariConfig();
    private static HikariDataSource crmDataSource;

    private static HikariConfig externalDatabaseConfig = new HikariConfig();
    private static HikariDataSource externalDataSource;

    public static void init() {
        initCRMDataSource();
        initexternalDataSource();
    }

    public static void initCRMDataSource() {


        String crmDriverClassName = ConfigUtils.getConfig("spring.datasource.driver-class-name");

        String crmDatabaseServer = ConfigUtils.getConfig("CR_DATABASE_SERVER");
        String crmDatabaseUserName = ConfigUtils.getConfig("CR_DATABASE_USER");
        String crmDatabasePassword = Encryptor.decrypt(ConfigUtils.getConfig("CR_DATABASE_USER_PASSWORD"));
        String crmDatabaseName = ConfigUtils.getConfig("CR_DATABASE_NAME");

        int crmPoolSize = ConfigUtils.getConfigNumeric("crm.maximum-pool-size");
        long crmConnectionTimeout = ConfigUtils.getConfigNumeric("crm.connection-timeout");
        long crmMaxLifeTime = ConfigUtils.getConfigNumeric("crm.max-lifetime");
        long crmIdleTimeout = ConfigUtils.getConfigNumeric("crm.idle-timeout");
        long crmLeakDetectionThreshold = ConfigUtils.getConfigNumeric("crm.leak-detection-threshold");

        String crmPoolName = ConfigUtils.getConfig("crm.pool-name");

        if (crmPoolSize > 0)
            crmConfig.setMaximumPoolSize(crmPoolSize);

        if (crmConnectionTimeout > 0)
            crmConfig.setConnectionTimeout(crmConnectionTimeout);

        if (crmMaxLifeTime > 0)
            crmConfig.setMaxLifetime(crmMaxLifeTime);

        if (crmIdleTimeout > 0)
            crmConfig.setIdleTimeout(crmIdleTimeout);

        if (crmLeakDetectionThreshold > 0)
            crmConfig.setLeakDetectionThreshold(crmLeakDetectionThreshold);

        crmConfig.setDriverClassName(crmDriverClassName);

        String crmJdbcUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://" + crmDatabaseServer + ";databaseName=" + crmDatabaseName
                + ";encrypt=false";
        crmConfig.setJdbcUrl(crmJdbcUrl);
        crmConfig.setUsername(crmDatabaseUserName);
        crmConfig.setPassword(crmDatabasePassword);
        if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(crmPoolName))
            crmConfig.setPoolName(crmPoolName);

        try {
            crmDataSource = new HikariDataSource(crmConfig);
            log.info("########## CRM DataSource Initialized Successfully ##############");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Exception in create crmDataSource,JdbcUrl: {},userName: {},Exception is: {}",
                    crmConfig.getJdbcUrl(), crmConfig.getUsername(), e.getMessage());
        }

    }

    public static void initexternalDataSource() {


        String externalDriverClassName = ConfigUtils.getConfig("spring.datasource.driver-class-name");

        String externalDatabaseServer = ConfigUtils.getConfig("CR_DATABASE_SERVER");
        String externalDatabaseUserName = ConfigUtils.getConfig("CR_DATABASE_USER");
        String externalDatabasePassword = Encryptor.decrypt(ConfigUtils.getConfig("CR_DATABASE_USER_PASSWORD"));
        String externalDatabaseName = ConfigUtils.getConfig("external_DATABASE_NAME");

        int externalPoolSize = ConfigUtils.getConfigNumeric("externalDatabase.maximum-pool-size");
        long externalConnectionTimeout = ConfigUtils.getConfigNumeric("externalDatabase.connection-timeout");
        long externalMaxLifeTime = ConfigUtils.getConfigNumeric("externalDatabase.max-lifetime");
        long externalIdleTimeout = ConfigUtils.getConfigNumeric("externalDatabase.idle-timeout");
        long externalLeakDetectionThreshold = ConfigUtils.getConfigNumeric("externalDatabase.leak-detection-threshold");

        String externalPoolName = ConfigUtils.getConfig("externalDatabase.pool-name");

        if (externalPoolSize > 0)
            externalDatabaseConfig.setMaximumPoolSize(externalPoolSize);

        if (externalConnectionTimeout > 0)
            externalDatabaseConfig.setConnectionTimeout(externalConnectionTimeout);

        if (externalMaxLifeTime > 0)
            externalDatabaseConfig.setMaxLifetime(externalMaxLifeTime);

        if (externalIdleTimeout > 0)
            externalDatabaseConfig.setIdleTimeout(externalIdleTimeout);

        if (externalLeakDetectionThreshold > 0)
            externalDatabaseConfig.setLeakDetectionThreshold(externalLeakDetectionThreshold);

        externalDatabaseConfig.setDriverClassName(externalDriverClassName);

        String externalJdbcUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://" + externalDatabaseServer + ";databaseName=" + externalDatabaseName
                + ";encrypt=false";
        externalDatabaseConfig.setJdbcUrl(externalJdbcUrl);
        externalDatabaseConfig.setUsername(externalDatabaseUserName);
        externalDatabaseConfig.setPassword(externalDatabasePassword);
        if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(externalPoolName))
            externalDatabaseConfig.setPoolName(externalPoolName);

        try {
            externalDataSource = new HikariDataSource(externalDatabaseConfig);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Exception in create externalDataSource,JdbcUrl: {},userName: {},Exception is: {}",
                    externalDatabaseConfig.getJdbcUrl(), externalDatabaseConfig.getUsername(), e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public static void closeDataSources() {
        log.info("crmDataSource SHUTDOWN");
        crmDataSource.close();
        log.info("externalDataSource SHUTDOWN");
        externalDataSource.close();
    }

    public static Connection getCRMConnection() throws SQLException {
        return crmDataSource.getConnection();
    }

    public static Connection getexternalConnection() throws SQLException {
        return externalDataSource.getConnection();
    }

    private HikariCPDataSource() {
    }
}
```

and call the init function on application context initialized.

**ISSUE**: when the database is down and I get some connection timeout exceptions as follows :

```
java.sql.SQLTransientConnectionException: crmPool - Connection is not available, request timed out after 36661ms.
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createTimeoutException(HikariPool.java:696) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:?]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.getConnection(HikariPool.java:197) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:?]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.getConnection(HikariPool.java:162) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:?]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:100) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:?]
    at com.myapp.dao.HikariCPDataSource.getCRMConnection(HikariCPDataSource.java:131) ~[classes/:1]
    at com.myapp.dao.MyRepository.getConnection(MyRepository.java:22) ~[classes/:1]
    at com.myapp.beans.MyBean.findClientRelatedCRs(MyBean.java:207) ~[classes/:1]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_281]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_281]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_281]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_281]
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:252) ~[jasper-el.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:266) ~[jasper-el.jar:9.0.71]
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:107) ~[javax.faces-2.3.9.jar:2.3.9]
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:87) ~[javax.faces-2.3.9.jar:2.3.9]
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102) ~[javax.faces-2.3.9.jar:2.3.9]
    at org.primefaces.application.DialogActionListener.processAction(DialogActionListener.java:54) ~[primefaces-12.0.0.jar:12.0.0]
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewAction.broadcast(UIViewAction.java:587) ~[javax.faces-2.3.9.jar:2.3.9]
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:870) ~[javax.faces-2.3.9.jar:2.3.9]
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1418) ~[javax.faces-2.3.9.jar:2.3.9]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:82) ~[javax.faces-2.3.9.jar:2.3.9]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:100) ~[javax.faces-2.3.9.jar:2.3.9]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:201) ~[javax.faces-2.3.9.jar:2.3.9]
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:670) ~[javax.faces-2.3.9.jar:2.3.9]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-websocket.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.ocpsoft.rewrite.servlet.RewriteFilter.doFilter(RewriteFilter.java:226) ~[rewrite-servlet-3.4.4.Final.jar:3.4.4.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:111) ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:111) ~[primefaces-12.0.0.jar:12.0.0]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:111) ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:111) ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:111) ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:711) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:459) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:385) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:313) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter$HeaderWriterRequestDispatcher.forward(HeaderWriterFilter.java:170) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.ocpsoft.rewrite.servlet.impl.HttpRewriteResultHandler.handleResult(HttpRewriteResultHandler.java:42) ~[rewrite-servlet-3.4.4.Final.jar:3.4.4.Final]
    at org.ocpsoft.rewrite.servlet.RewriteFilter.rewrite(RewriteFilter.java:297) ~[rewrite-servlet-3.4.4.Final.jar:3.4.4.Final]
    at org.ocpsoft.rewrite.servlet.RewriteFilter.doFilter(RewriteFilter.java:198) ~[rewrite-servlet-3.4.4.Final.jar:3.4.4.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:94) ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:111) ~[primefaces-12.0.0.jar:12.0.0]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.71]
    at com.myapp.AjaxTimeoutFilter.doFilter(AjaxTimeoutFilter.java:71) ~[classes/:1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:337) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:115) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:81) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:122) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:116) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:126) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:81) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:109) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:149) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:166) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:223) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:217) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at com.myapp.CaptchaAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(CaptchaAuthenticationFilter.java:72) ~[classes/:1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:103) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:89) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:112) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:82) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:55) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter.doFilterInternal(DisableEncodeUrlFilter.java:42) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:221) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:186) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:354) ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:267) ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:96) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.7.4.jar:2.7.4]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:126) ~[spring-boot-2.7.4.jar:2.7.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.access$000(ErrorPageFilter.java:64) ~[spring-boot-2.7.4.jar:2.7.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter$1.doFilterInternal(ErrorPageFilter.java:101) ~[spring-boot-2.7.4.jar:2.7.4]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:119) ~[spring-boot-2.7.4.jar:2.7.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:177) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:687) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:360) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:891) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1784) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-util.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-util.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-util.jar:9.0.71]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_281]
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The TCP/IP connection to the host 10.10.50.123, port 55225 has failed. Error: "The timeout expired before connecting to the routing destination.". ClientConnectionId:5d1c4012-43a1-409b-accd-dffd822cdfc7
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.terminate(SQLServerConnection.java:3806) ~[mssql-jdbc-11.2.1.jre8.jar:?]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.terminate(SQLServerConnection.java:3795) ~[mssql-jdbc-11.2.1.jre8.jar:?]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:3006) ~[mssql-jdbc-11.2.1.jre8.jar:?]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectInternal(SQLServerConnection.java:2790) ~[mssql-jdbc-11.2.1.jre8.jar:?]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:1663) ~[mssql-jdbc-11.2.1.jre8.jar:?]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:1064) ~[mssql-jdbc-11.2.1.jre8.jar:?]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:?]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:364) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:?]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:206) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:?]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:476) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:?]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.access$100(HikariPool.java:71) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:?]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool$PoolEntryCreator.call(HikariPool.java:726) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:?]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool$PoolEntryCreator.call(HikariPool.java:712) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_281]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_281]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_281]
    ... 1 more
```

After that I get `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError,exception message is: Java heap space`

While enabling debug, I see the following logs :

```
crmPool - Closing connection ConnectionID:335466 ClientConnectionId: 16cef5bd-2ea3-44e5-a44f-ba5c66c0eeb1: (connection has passed maxLifetime)
crmPool - Add connection elided, waiting 0, queue 483
crmPool - After adding stats (total=117, active=0, idle=117, waiting=0)
```

This is strange also because the total should be 600 and also why the connections go to queue ?

Is there's something I need to change in my Configuration in order to avoid this issue ?

Comment: Could you add stack trace of OOME?

Comment: Are you sure that your SQL server is capable to handle that much connections ?  Because the timeout might happen because the server refuses (or have trouble) to handle as many connections, and the OOM might just be a side-effect of the fact that you have 100+ connections alive client-side. Hikari provides a [pool sizing documentation](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/wiki/About-Pool-Sizing) to help you understand all of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for first question

> This is strange also because the total should be 600 and also why the connections go to queue ?

that is a "connection" open queue as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64319099/175554). And for second question check below.

Configuration is missing socket timeout configuration as described [here](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/wiki/Rapid-Recovery#tcp-timeouts)

> In order to avoid this condition, it is imperative that the application configures the driver-level TCP socket timeout. Each driver differs in how this timeout is set, but nearly all drivers support it.

> HikariCP recommends that the driver-level socket timeout be set to (at least) 2-3x the longest running SQL transaction, or 30 seconds, whichever is longer. However, your own recovery time targets should determine the appropriate timeout for your application.

For MS SQL doc is [here](https://github.com/microsoft/mssql-jdbc/wiki/SocketTimeout)

> connection URL jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;userName=sa;password=PASSW0RD;database=master;socketTimeout=10000;

If socketTimeout is not defined then that tcp connection waits forever and probably that creates the **OutOfMemoryError**.

In order to fix OutOfMemoryError, you can lower **crm.maximum-pool-size=600** or [increase/fine tune xmx and xms values of the jvm](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14763095/175554). last but not least why not upgrade to java 17. Java 8 is pretty old and every jvm brings more performance improvements.